# Laravel Passport Get Client ID from Bearer Token

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, bearer-token

I've set up the laravel passport and created clients. When clients make a post request to my application using it api, all they send is the bearer access token along with the post values.

Is there any way I can get the client id of the consuming application when they submit the post request simply from the bearer token.

Or is it entirely safe for the consuming application to send their client id along with the post fields?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what i need:

```
$request->user()->token()->client
```

Comment: This assumes a user is associated. For example, if you use the grant type client_credentials, there is no associated user.

Answer (score 1):

If you deal with the [**grant type client_credentials**](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens) you might consider the following solution:

```
Route::get('/get-client-cred', function (Request $request) {
    $bearerToken = $request->bearerToken();

    $tokenId = (new \Lcobucci\JWT\Parser())->parse($bearerToken)->getHeader('jti');

    return \Laravel\Passport\Token::find($tokenId)->client;
})->middleware('client_credentials');
```

Instead, if you are dealing with a **personal access token** you can retrieve the client as following:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/get-client', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user()->token()->client;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `passport` you can get the user id from the `Auth` facade using `api guard` like this:

```
$user_id = Auth::guard('api')->id();
```

or get the user:

```
$user = Auth::guard('api')->user();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked for me with Laravel 8.

Note that I plagerised the solution from @judge2020's [answer on GitHub](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/124).

```
use Laravel\Passport\Token;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Configuration; /* composer require lcobucci/jwt */

Route::get('/v1/test', function(Request $request) {   

    $bearerToken = request()->bearerToken();
    $tokenId = Configuration::forUnsecuredSigner()->parser()->parse($bearerToken)->claims()->get('jti');
    $client = Token::find($tokenId)->client;
    
})->middleware('client');
```